# Regular expression and method to separate characters in C#

Tags: c#, regex

What would be the regular expression to convert "Family/Car" in "Family / Car"?

```
public string formatedName(string noFormatedName)
{
    string fomatedName = ?¿??; //I want "Family / Car"
    return formatedName;
}
```

when noFormatedName = "Family/Car" --> formatedName will return "Family / Car"
But if noFormatedName  = "Family / Car" --> formatedName will not change the string and it will return "Family / Car"

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fomatedName = Regex.Replace(familyName, "[ ]*/[ ]*", " / ");
```

Comment: @MichaleT the proble is that i want a generic form to do that, and this is not valid to a string like "Family / Car". it will be transformed in "Family  /  Car"... I am going to change my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace:

> String formatedName = familyName.Replace("/", " / ");

Comment: the proble is that i want a generic form to do that, and this is not valid to a string like "Family / Car". it will be transformed in "Family / Car"... I have changed my question to do it more clear